# Get width of svg element from uploaded file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I selected a svg file and read it via `readDataUrl(<file>)`, I can set it to an html `image element` by setting the `src` to be the value read from the file. However the width and height attributes will be 0. How can I set the value read from a file to an `svg element` in order to be able to do a `getBBox()`.width to obtain its width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XMLHttpRequest (or your favourite AJAX library) to read and parse the SVG file.  I imagine you can even just pass the dataurl to it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**, *because I misread the question :*

- If you can append the svg to your document, and need to use a FileReader, use its [`readAsText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) method, then insert it in an html element.

```js
function previewFile() {
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    var parent = document.getElementById('container');
    parent.innerHTML= reader.result;
  }

  if (file && file.type=="image/svg+xml") {
    reader.readAsText(file);
  } else {
    alert("wrong file type or no file provided");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
```

- If you don't need to use a FileReader (e.g if the file is saved on the server), Paul's answer is better.
- If you don't want to actually append the svg file but only know its width/height, you can refer to my

**original answer :**

I don't think you can get the height from the data url.
As a workaround, you can use the [`readAsText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText)method of the fileReader API, combined with the [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) method, in order to read the `viewBox` property of the svg.

```js
function xlog(msg){
 document.getElementById('log').textContent = msg;
 }
function previewFile() {
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(reader.result, 'application/xml');
 var viewBox = doc.documentElement.viewBox.baseVal;
 xlog('height:'+viewBox.height+' width:'+viewBox.width);
  }

  if (file && file.type=="image/svg+xml") {
    reader.readAsText(file);
  } else {
    xlog("wrong file type or no file provided");
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="log"></p><br>
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
```

Note that you can append the `doc.documentElement` into your document and then get the element's BBox.